# Ecto validation fails with no error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to create a basic CRUD app, but I'm having problems with validation.  here's my controller action:

```
def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "user" => params}) do
  case Repo.get(User, String.to_integer(id)) do
    user when is_map(user) ->
      user = Map.merge(user, atomize_keys(params))
      case User.validate(user) do
        [] ->
          Repo.update(user)
          redirect conn, to: user_path(:show, user.id)
        errors ->
          text conn, "Validation Failed!"
          ##render conn, "editform.html", user: user, errors: errors
      end
    _ ->
      redirect conn, to: user_path(:index)
  end
end
```

and my model:

```
defmodule MyApp.User do
  use Ecto.Model
  validate user, 
   email: present()

  schema "users" do
   field :first_name, :string
   field :last_name, :string
   field :email, :string
   field :created_at, :datetime, default: Ecto.DateTime.local
   field :updated_at, :datetime, default: Ecto.DateTime.local
  end
end
```

User.validate(user) seems to be returning something, but not an error- no error shows up in the form.html.  What am I missing here? Could this be a problem with the atomize_keys() function? Here is that one:

```
defp atomize_keys(struct) do
  Enum.reduce struct, %{}, fn({k, v}, map) 
  -> Map.put(map,  String.to_atom(k), v) end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I tagged it but failed to mention that this is Elixir with the Phoenix Framework.

Comment: Quick question? What version of ecto are you running? Newer versions (>0.7) uses changesets instead of validate. Might be part of the problem...

Comment: I'm at work now and this is my home project, but I did check into the Ecto source and found present() is a function.  It also does not fail compilation which makes me think the 'validate' macro is present.  I'll check the version tonight- can you point me in the direction of the documentation for the later versions?

Comment: Yeah, check out
http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html

And specifically:
http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#validate_change/3

Comment: Allright, as it turns out, I had an older version of Ecto.  I cloned Ecto 9.0, and the Phoenix 0.10, and after a few hours messing with it, cannot connect to the db.  I've got my config set up in confix.exs, but I'm getting 'invalid password' message.  The password works when using psql in the terminal :-/  any suggestions on the new version of ecto?

Comment: You'll need something like this in your config/config.exs:

    config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
    adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
    database: "my_app",
    username: "my_name",
    password: "",
    server: "localhost"

* Really sorry, the 4-indent code block just isn't working here.

Comment: @hahuang65 You should post that as an answer so others can see it as well.  Right now your response is buried in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your configuration should look like:

```
# config/config.exs
use Mix.Config

# Your endpoint config and your logger config go here...

# DB config:
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
   adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
   database: "myapp",
   username: "username",
   password: "password",
   server: "localhost"
```

Then your model can look like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.User do
  use Ecto.Model

  schema "users" do
    field :first_name, :string
    field :last_name, :string
    field :email, :string
    field :created_at, :datetime, default: Ecto.DateTime.local
    field :updated_at, :datetime, default: Ecto.DateTime.local
  end

  def changeset(params, :create) do
    # Read the docs for Ecto.Changeset.cast, by including email in the second argument, it becomes required, the third argument are the optional arguments. Anything not in these two lists will be dropped out of the passed in params.
    # User validate_change for other custom validations.
    %User{}
    |> cast(params, ~w(email), ~(first_name last_name)
    |> validate_unique(:email, on: MyApp.Repo)
  end

  def changeset(params, :update, user) do
    user
    |> cast(params, [], ~w(email first_name last_name))
    |> validate_unique(:email, on: MyApp.Repo)
  end
end
```

The nice part of this model code means your controller can look like:

```
def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "user" => params}) do
  user = MyApp.Repo.get(User, id)

  case user do
    %MyApp.User{} ->
      changeset = User.changeset(params, :update, user)

      if changeset.valid? do
        Repo.update(changeset)
        redirect conn, to: user_path(:show, user.id)
      else
        render conn "editform.html", user: user, errors: changeset.errors
      end
    _ ->
      redirect conn, to: user_path(:index)
  end
end
```

Comment: Caveat, I haven't used Phoenix views for HTML much, so the render and redirect stuff might need double checking. But the rest of the controller stuff should be pretty solid.

Comment: I ended up getting this working with something similar to the above- but the config was pulling db connection data from the dev.exs, not the config one.  Also, apparently Repo file has a home now, instead of being dumped in with models in previous versions.